# How to shorten if statement code in Python

Tags: python, dataframe, if-statement

I have this Pandas DataFrame

[image]

I'm attempting to create a new column named **Needed** using the code below. The rule is:

In case of **"KHOÁ NHÓM"**, for EVERY 25 **giohoc**, **Needed** = **dauvao_overall** **+ 0.5**.

In case of **"KHOÁ KÈM"**, for EVERY 20  **giohoc**, **Needed** = **dauvao_overall** **+ 0.5**.

My idea is to divide **giohoc** by 25 for "KHOÁ NHÓM" and 20 for "KHOÁ KÈM".

If the result < 1 then **Needed** = **dauvao_overall.**

If the result >=1 and <2 then **Needed** = **dauvao_overall + 0.5.**

If the result >=2 and <3 then **Needed** = **dauvao_overall + 1.**

All the way up to .... **Needed** = **dauvao_overall + 7.**

Although I succeeded, I believe there is a shorter and cleaner way to achieve the same result. Please tell me what I can do to improve the code. Thank you!

```
empty =[]
for index, row in didiem.iterrows():
        # KHOÁ NHÓM
        if row.group_kh_ten == "KHOÁ NHÓM" and row.giohoc/25 < 1:
                empty.append(row.dauvao_overall)
        elif row.group_kh_ten == "KHOÁ NHÓM" and row.giohoc/25 >= 1 and row.giohoc/25 <2:
                empty.append(row.dauvao_overall + 0.5)
        elif row.group_kh_ten == "KHOÁ NHÓM" and row.giohoc/25 >= 2 and row.giohoc/25 <3:
                empty.append(row.dauvao_overall + 1)
        elif row.group_kh_ten == "KHOÁ NHÓM" and row.giohoc/25 >= 3 and row.giohoc/25 <4:
                empty.append(row.dauvao_overall + 1.5)
        elif row.group_kh_ten == "KHOÁ NHÓM" and row.giohoc/25 >= 4 and row.giohoc/25 <5:
                empty.append(row.dauvao_overall + 2)
        elif row.group_kh_ten == "KHOÁ NHÓM" and row.giohoc/25 >= 5 and row.giohoc/25 <6:
                empty.append(row.dauvao_overall + 2.5)
        elif row.group_kh_ten == "KHOÁ NHÓM" and row.giohoc/25 >= 6 and row.giohoc/25 <7:
                empty.append(row.dauvao_overall + 3)
        elif row.group_kh_ten == "KHOÁ NHÓM" and row.giohoc/25 >= 7 and row.giohoc/25 <8:
                empty.append(row.dauvao_overall + 3.5)
        elif row.group_kh_ten == "KHOÁ NHÓM" and row.giohoc/25 >= 8 and row.giohoc/25 <9:
                empty.append(row.dauvao_overall + 4.0)
        elif row.group_kh_ten == "KHOÁ NHÓM" and row.giohoc/25 >= 9 and row.giohoc/25 <10:
                empty.append(row.dauvao_overall + 4.5)
        elif row.group_kh_ten == "KHOÁ NHÓM" and row.giohoc/25 >= 10 and row.giohoc/25 <11:
                empty.append(row.dauvao_overall + 5)
        elif row.group_kh_ten == "KHOÁ NHÓM" and row.giohoc/20 >= 14 and row.giohoc/20 <15:
                empty.append(row.dauvao_overall + 7.0)
        # KHOÁ KÈM
        elif row.group_kh_ten == "KHOÁ KÈM" and row.giohoc/20 < 1:
                empty.append(row.dauvao_overall) 
        elif row.group_kh_ten == "KHOÁ KÈM" and row.giohoc/20 >= 1 and row.giohoc/20 <2:
                empty.append(row.dauvao_overall + 0.5)
        elif row.group_kh_ten == "KHOÁ KÈM" and row.giohoc/20 >= 2 and row.giohoc/20 <3:
                empty.append(row.dauvao_overall + 1)
        elif row.group_kh_ten == "KHOÁ KÈM" and row.giohoc/20 >= 3 and row.giohoc/20 <4:
                empty.append(row.dauvao_overall + 1.5) 
        elif row.group_kh_ten == "KHOÁ KÈM" and row.giohoc/20 >= 4 and row.giohoc/20 <5:
                empty.append(row.dauvao_overall + 2)
        elif row.group_kh_ten == "KHOÁ KÈM" and row.giohoc/20 >= 5 and row.giohoc/20 <6:
                empty.append(row.dauvao_overall + 2.5) 
        elif row.group_kh_ten == "KHOÁ KÈM" and row.giohoc/20 >= 6 and row.giohoc/20 <7:
                empty.append(row.dauvao_overall + 3)
        elif row.group_kh_ten == "KHOÁ KÈM" and row.giohoc/20 >= 7 and row.giohoc/20 <8:
                empty.append(row.dauvao_overall + 3.5) 
        elif row.group_kh_ten == "KHOÁ KÈM" and row.giohoc/20 >= 8 and row.giohoc/20 <9:
                empty.append(row.dauvao_overall + 4.0)
        elif row.group_kh_ten == "KHOÁ KÈM" and row.giohoc/20 >= 9 and row.giohoc/20 <10:
                empty.append(row.dauvao_overall + 4.5)
        elif row.group_kh_ten == "KHOÁ KÈM" and row.giohoc/20 >= 10 and row.giohoc/20 <11:
                empty.append(row.dauvao_overall + 5.0)
        elif row.group_kh_ten == "KHOÁ KÈM" and row.giohoc/20 >= 11 and row.giohoc/20 <12:
                empty.append(row.dauvao_overall + 5.5)
        elif row.group_kh_ten == "KHOÁ KÈM" and row.giohoc/20 >= 12 and row.giohoc/20 <13:
                empty.append(row.dauvao_overall + 6.0)
        elif row.group_kh_ten == "KHOÁ KÈM" and row.giohoc/20 >= 13 and row.giohoc/20 <14:
                empty.append(row.dauvao_overall + 6.5)
        elif row.group_kh_ten == "KHOÁ KÈM" and row.giohoc/20 >= 14 and row.giohoc/20 <15:
                empty.append(row.dauvao_overall + 7.0)
        elif row.group_kh_ten == "KHOÁ KÈM" and row.giohoc/20 >= 15 and row.giohoc/20 <16:
                empty.append(row.dauvao_overall + 7.5)
        else:
                empty.append("inspect")
didiem["Needed"] = empty
```

Comment: rather than give us this huge code dump with a bunch of magic numbers how about you explain in plain english the rules to go from input to output ... why are some 20 and some 25 ... and whats the deal with the >= thresholds etc

Comment: @JoranBeasley  I edited the question. Thank you for your advice. I'm sorry, I should have done that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank to the formula of @AndrzejO and @Joran Beasley:

**needed = overall + (giohoc // 25) * 0.5**

I figured out an even shorter way.

```
empty =[]
for index, row in didiem.iterrows():
        # KHOÁ NHÓM
        if row.group_kh_ten == "KHOÁ NHÓM":
                empty.append(row.dauvao_overall + row.giohoc//25 * 0.5)
        # KHOÁ KÈM
        elif row.group_kh_ten == "KHOÁ KÈM":
                empty.append(row.dauvao_overall + row.giohoc//20 * 0.5)
        else:
                empty.append("Null")
didiem["Needed"] = empty
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this will do what you want (I only solved it for one of your cases...)

```
import numpy
import pandas
num_rows = 1000
# some random values between 2 and 10 for this column
dauvao_overall = numpy.random.uniform(2,10,num_rows)
# some random values between 1 and 200 for this column
giohoc = numpy.random.randint(1,200,num_rows)
# some random values for this column
group_kh_ten = numpy.random.choice(["KHOA NHOM","KHOA KEM"],num_rows)

#make a dataframe

df = pandas.DataFrame({"dauvao_overall":dauvao_overall,"giohoc":giohoc, "group_kh_ten":group_kh_ten})
df['needed'] = 0



# here is how you would solve KHOA KEM
khoa_kem = df['group_kh_ten']=='KHOA KEM'
df.loc[khoa_kem,"needed"] = (df[khoa_kem]['dauvao_overall'] + 0.5) * (df[khoa_kem]['giohoc']//25)
print(df)
```

Answer (score 1):

First, define a function which will calculate the `Needed` value. It will receive a dataframe row, and do the calculations.

```
def fun(row):
    group_kh, overall, giohoc = [row[col_name] 
                                for col_name in ['group_kh_ten', 'dauvao_overall',  'giohoc']]
    match group_kh:
        
        case 'KHOÁ NHÓM': 
            needed = overall + (giohoc // 25) * 0.5
        
        case 'KHOÁ KÈM' : 
            needed = overall + (giohoc // 20) * 0.5
            if giohoc // 20 >= 16: needed = 'inspect'
        
        case _ : 
            print("error: wrong group_kh_ten")
            
    return needed
```

Apply the function on each row of the dataframe:

```
df['Needed'] = df.apply(fun, axis=1)
```

Example:

```
    group_kh_ten    dauvao_overall  giohoc
0   KHOÁ NHÓM       2.0             70.0
1   KHOÁ KÈM        3.5             80.0
```

Apply the function `fun`:

```
df['Needed'] = df.apply(fun, axis=1)
```

Output:

```
    group_kh_ten    dauvao_overall  giohoc  Needed
0   KHOÁ NHÓM       2.0             70.0    3.0
1   KHOÁ KÈM        3.5             80.0    5.5
```